# Chrome Submit form and navigate window in Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, google-chrome

So I have an app that submits a form to an external cart using Javascript (target is blank) then I want the window to navigate to a Rails controller to create a small tracker model, controller as such:

```
def add_to_cart
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.cart_trackers.create
    redirect_to :back
end
```

And the Javascript (in a link_to, onclick helper):

```
document.forms['addCart#{product.id}'].submit();
window.location.href=\"/products/add_to_cart/#{product.id}\";
return false;
```

And this works wonderfully in Firefox and Internet Explorer, but Google Chrome throws a fit about so much navigation. I realize AJAX could be a worthy solution, but due to the environment this app runs under (which is a clustercrap of Prototype, Jquery, iFrames, and includes) I'd like to avoid it if possible. Chrome's response is to actually run the *window.location...* code and skip the form submitting. Without one or the other lines of code, Chrome will perform the single action just fine.

So, what would be the proper way of writing this out? Or should I give in and just wrangle in some AJAX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using AJAX-but-not-really-AJAX.  Submit the form using whatever AJAX submitter you want (e.g., $.ajax), but don't do anything with the response (i.e., no callback).  That way the data gets POSTed and maybe the browser won't be upset that you're asking it to visit two urls back-to-back.

Comment: So AJAX would seem to be the way to go? Again, from past developers, it's tough to follow their script imports and renaming conventions (they constantly assigning new variables to jQuery.noConflict()) So getting jQuery or Prototype to work at the end of the funnel is semi-nightmarish

Comment: It might be something you can do without getting tangled up in all that.  AJAX sort of implies two-way communication - i.e. you hit the server and it sends back a response.  All you really need to do here is hit the server it looks like.   Alternatively - can you just do both steps from the controller?  Submit the form and then the controller redirects to /products/add_to_cart/#{product.id}?

Comment: That would work but the form submits externally outside the app